# Firebase PhoneAuthentication for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

Im need to use Firebase PhoneAuthentication for my XF project but it's didn't work.
Does anyone have any sample project or code to solve this problem ?

Comment: Integrating Firebase Auth in Xamarin.Forms is very easy and basic .What we need is to create a .NET Core WEB API project to validate Firebase Auth token and return simple data . Check https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/03/26/firebase-authentication-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: It is a good idea to look here before implementing: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

Because there is a captcha authentication for iOS. In other hand, this document can help if you want to implement: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firebase-auth-on-xamarin-forms-171432aa3d76

Answer (score 0):

thank you guy, im using this Nuget Package and it's work fine.
https://github.com/f-miyu/Plugin.FirebaseAuth